# Promise.all is not resolving promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, hardhat

I am deploying solidity contracts using Hardhat for which I have written this deploy script:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const erc20Tokens = ["Solana", "USDC", "Doge"];
  const initialSupply = ethers.utils.parseUnits("100", "ether");
  async function deploy(token) {
    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory(token);
    console.log(`deploying ERC20 ${token} contract...`);
    const deployedToken = await Token.deploy(initialSupply);
    await deployedToken.deployed();
    return deployedToken.address;
    // console.log(`deployed ERC20 ${token} at: `, deployedToken.address);
  }
  const resolveAllPromises = erc20Tokens.map(async (e) => deploy(e));

  Promise.all(resolveAllPromises).then(e=>console.log("resolved",e)).catch(err=>console.log("err"))
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("error: ", err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

I am not getting the returned value of `deployedToken.address` from the deploy function even though the console.log in the deploy function is not executing. What's the issue here? May anyone help me out

Comment: `return Promise.all` You  broke your promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

`return Promise.all`. You broke your promise chain.